# Translate %SystemRoot% to Actual Path Using Java

Tags: java, registry

I'm successfully pulling values from the registry, but some contain the '%SystemRoot%' value. Is there a way in Java I can find out what that equates to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an environment variable, and you can access it with [`System.getenv(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv-java.lang.String-) like

```
String sysRoot = System.getenv("SystemRoot");
```